# Heroku JAX-RS POST

Tags: java, heroku, jax-rs

### Scenario:

Recently, our team created an application on Heroku. We got all of our environments set up inside eclipse and became familiar with Git. I was able to change some code and at least see that I could manipulate an http GET request to return the results that I wanted. My mission now, is to try to get POST working.

Right now, we have a simple TestService where you can retrieve JSON objects from by doing something like this: myurl.com/services/test/test1 and it will return the JSON object:

{
  "name": "test1",
  "test": 100
}

### Code:

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestService
{
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public TestObject get()
    {
        return new TestObject();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{name}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public TestObject get(@PathParam("name") String name)
    {
        return TestObject.getObject(name);
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void post(final TestObject object)
    {
        TestObject.postObject(object.getName(), object);
    }

}
```

### Question:

A) How to set up this code for an http POST request?

B) How to actually request it like the above GET request?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you asking how to exercise the POST method from a client? Or are you asking something about the implementation of the POST method?

Answer (score 0):

A) If I get you right, you're looking for how to set up the POST method on your service. Try this, which is almost what you have right now. Have a look at the return type which is javax.ws.rs.core.Response.

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public static Response post(
  String testObjectAsJson){      

  TestObject testObject = testObjectAsJson.toEntity; //some json deserialization function
  //do something with testObject


  //return a status of 200 to the client
  return Response.status(200).build;
}
```

If you want to process your testObject and return the modified one try this:

```
String testObjectAsJson = testObject.toJson; //some json conversion method
return Response.status(200).entity(testObjectAsJson).build;
```

B) For testing your request e.g. use chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html in firefox. (maybe you have to add it first under add-ons). There you can send POST requests to your service.